# Efficient data structure for phone book

Tags: data-structures, trie, avl-tree

I have implemented a phone book using AVL trees. But many say Trie is most suitable for implementing a phonebook. Should i change my project to Trie or is there any other good reasons where AVL tree woud be more efficient than Trie in case of phonebook.

Comment: What operations are you trying to optimize? What's important to you? How many entries are in the phone book? (I assume this is just a toy project or assignment, but the details will influence which data structure you should choose.)

Answer (score 0):

A trie is an index structure that is particularly useful when the keys vary in length.

An AVL (Adelson-Velskii and Landis) tree is a binary search tree with a balance condition.

In real use, Trie is preferred when `N` is large but `L` (Length) is not very large and words are not that random, like to store an English dictionary.
But when `L` is very large and the ‘words’ are random, like to store random generated long
passwords, long hash values, etc., It’s better to choose AVL Tree.

For more information check this [pdf](http://www.cs.zju.edu.cn/ds/upload/201312/20131202103407625.pdf) which is an analysis of difference between these two tree structures.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting an appropriate data structure is about optimizing specific tasks to meet your most important features.

ie.) a phone book needs to be searched extremely fast so a linked list would be a terrible option as its Big-O is to the order of N for search times.

An AVL tree does have an average search time of (log n) however, this is implying you have some sort of hierarchical order to sort the tree with.

My personal suggestion would be a bucket hash (a hash table of linked lists). Although it is a little complex you can use their name as a Key for your hash function and people with the same key can be stored in a linked list (n search time). Although the big O of this is still N its average case run time is drastically reduced when you consider the constant factors that are typically ignored.